# How to fill transaction nounce gap for an EOA?

Tags: transactions, nonce

If for whatever the reason, one transaction submitted (say lost transaction with nonce `N`) was not mined into block. The consequence is that any transactions submitted after the lost transaction will not be mined. In order to move ahead, a transaction with nonce `N` has to be mined. My question is what is the easy way to submit a transaction with nonce `N` and get it mined?

Comment: "the easy way to submit a transaction with nonce N" is......

Comment: Submit a transaction with nonce N.

Comment: In order to increase the probability of that transaction getting mined, you need to increase the gas price.

Comment: I meant the purpose of the transaction is meaningless except increase of nonce. What type of transaction is meaningless with high possibility to be mined? Shall a smart contract be deployed for this purpose?

Comment: Transferring ether to yourself would be meaningless enough I suppose (and would not require deploying or using a smart contract). You'd still be spending the gas though.